# Wordpress Sidebar menu - Add folding menu subitems functionality

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress Sidebar menu that is becoming too long so I need just to have the menu items show and not the sub-items.

Does anyone know how to add folding menu subitems functionality to it please?

I am using a plugin called: wp-wiki and I have added:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('post_type=wiki'); ?>
```

So, I get a list of pages. That's all good but I don't want the subpages on the sidebar.php page, or at least not showing all the time.

Thanks

Comment: what are you showing on your sidebar, and what widgets are you using to show them?

Comment: I'm edited my question. Please see answer to your question above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php wp_list_pages('post_type=wiki&depth=1'); ?>
```